# Create new div with different %width

Tags: javascript, css, width

I've created a section with one div. 
The button 'click' adds new div each time when I click. 
What I need: div 1 -> 100% width (section)
when I click:
div 1 and div2 (div 2 new) -> get 50% width each.
click again:
div1, div2 and div3 -> 30% width each. 
click again:
div 4 goes to next line with the same width

Do you have any idea?
https://jsfiddle.net/Vova_Champion/tcyw64wq/6/

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  let ok = true;
  if (ok === true) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'new-div';

    document.getElementsByTagName('section')[0].appendChild(div);
  }
};
```

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

div {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 30%;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px 2px;
}

#button {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Click button</button>
<section id="section">
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this div style:

```
div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display:block;
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 30%;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px 2px;
}
```

"Flex-grow" gives them "weight" inside the div, items with the same flex grow share the same portion of the available space. Min-width triggers the 4th div to go down since adding that to the same line would make their width 25%.

If you need any further explanation, please ask!

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest some flex-grow and a conditional class to fix width after 3 items. Here is my try ;)

I have also used css calc.

```js
(function() {
  const section = document.getElementById('section');

  function addDiv() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'new-div';
    section.appendChild(div);

    if (section.childNodes.length > 3) {
      section.classList.add("fixedWith");
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    addDiv();
  };

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    addDiv();
  });
})();
```

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: calc(100% / 3 - 4px);
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px 2px;
}

section.fixedWith div {
  max-width: calc(100% / 3 - 4px);
}

#button {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button id="button">Click button</button>
  <section id="section"></section>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: thanks hyde, the first line works well, but the second starts with width 30% ... but I needed the same as the first line. Anyway thanks for try! AngelMdez solved it.

Comment: I see, I thought that this was the feature you were looking for ;) "div 4 goes to next line with the same width". Anyway good that it is solved for you.

Answer (score 0):

Putting flex: 1 on the div says that it will take 1 fraction of the space in its parent. When another div is added, it then takes 1 of the two available fractions of space and so on. The flex-basis: 30%; effectively says that each flex item can take at most 30% of the available space for that row. Hopefully this fixes your problem!

```
section {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

div {
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px 2px;
}

#button {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks John, almost ... the fourth element should go down the next line, but it (like all the following) remain in the first line. I need to have 3 divs per line ...

Comment: Min-width set to 30% in the div will make it.